# How to insert at symbol ( @ ) in equation?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need to insert an at symbol, @ , which I know how to do in text, but can't figure out how to do in mathmode. Detexify gives me only text mode symbol for LaTeX.

Comment: Both `@` and `$@$` work for me.  Can you provide an example of what you've tried or the mode of failure?

Comment: Ok, since you told me it should just work I went through my code and you are right. It was a parameter to a macro that inserted a backslash before it! - like this: \@ .

Comment: Now it works. How do I close this question? @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: I believe there should be a button to delete the question which you can perform.

Comment: Welcomet to TeX.SX!

Comment: Or you could reformulate your question if your additional probing has allowed you to distill the problem more precisely.  Note that macro names (beginning with \\) have special rules about their naming conventions, especially if it involves not alphabetic symbols.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a non problem due to typing \@ instead of @

Comment: Yes, I flagged my own post to close it. It's "indirect" typing problem - my latex is being generated by python...

Comment: You can create your   equation in the "StackExchange" Mathematics site and then copy pasted here. For example in this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321736/the-fourier-series-sum-n-1-infty-1-n-cos-nx    I copy/pasted this ∑ simbol or this: ∫xπdC(x)dx  as you see is not perfect. The x should be down in the integral and the π up, but is a good start. I think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @StevenB.Segletes mentioned in the comments, plain @ should work, in math or text mode. I had somehow managed generate a \@ , which throws the following error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
\@->\spacefactor
```

Corrected my code and now everything is working.